# Unable to launch any container on CentOS

Tags: docker, centos-7

I am new using Docker. I want to install docker-ce on a CentOS Linux host.

When I tried to run my container doing:

```
docker run -it hello-world
```

I got this error:

```
mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/c467890Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf" caused:
mount through procfd: possibly malicious path detected
refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf: unknown**
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Certainly because of `c467890Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` folder name.

Comment: i have crypted to put the question ! it is not Certainly not the true name :D Sorry

Comment: **c467890Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx** is to replace **dc97b4f7d121fb58e49117d1da8c26ac3398ed7bb76410f68ea134a6096a8e68** @Toto

Answer (score 4):

On my old CentOS 7 (3.10.0-229), I solved it by downgrading docker.

I followed this site:
https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_43798031/article/details/121419229

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop docker

sudo yum remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

sudo yum install containerd.io-1.3.7-3.1.el7
sudo yum install docker-ce-19.03.4  docker-ce-cli-19.03.4

sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: I had the same problem on that exact kernel on Centos7. Downgrading Docker alone from 20.10 to 19.03 did not help, but downgrading also containerd.io did the job. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! Or week...

Comment: I had the same problem on my  Centos 7 ( 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64) and this fixed it. Thanks